# Java Edit Jar File

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jar, edit, decompiler

I have a jar file which includes seviral classes. In that jar there is a Confirmation.class file which i want to edit.  I decompiled that class by usin JAD. Then i edit it with notepad++ and saved as .java file.

Now how can i create my new jar file with other classes?

Other files format is .class but mine is .java, is it problem?

If it is , how can i compile my .java class ? (when i use command javac Confirmation.java it gives errors and want other classes)

Thanks..

Comment: Your command is not correct. You will have to tell the compiler where to find the .java, .class files Confirmation.java depends on. Read here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Does the lincence under which the jar is provided even permit changes to the source code?

Comment: I haven't know how to call multiple classes in command. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have dependencies to other jars?

If this is the case, you will have to put them on the compiler classpath in advance.

In any case, just decompile all the package (I use jd-gui), change the class, compile, open the original jar as a zip, put the new class on it, and you are done.

Another approach is to create dummy classes for the missing dependencies...

Personally, I really discourage this approach of "reverse engineering" working with an already compiled package, but I understand situations where you don't have access to the original source code, but you need to fix something urgently (ex: working in a company, where your code comes from an external provider on the other side of the planet...)

Comment: yes there is dependency to another jar file. As you said im working in company and codes come from different provider :)

Comment: And you don't have access to these jars? If is not the case, what I did in the past, even if it sounds "cheap", is to create dummy empty classes to match exactly the import's of the class I want to compile.

Comment: no i have that another jar too. But there is no need to change anything in it. All i want is adding a variable and get() set() methods for only one class.

Comment: No, you can not edit. It was just a comment of what I am using. I don't know with JAD, but with JD-GUI you can decompile all the package into .java classes mantaining the structure, something that will help you in order to do changes and then recompile

Answer (score 0):

You may try to copy & paste the code in Java IDE such as `Eclipse`, `NetBeans`, etc and ask the IRC to compile for u. Have a nice day :)